# WCF error - No endpoint listening at url

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap

"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:52154"I am getting the following error:

> There was no endpoint listening at
>   http://localhost:52154/DocumentGenerator.svc that could accept the
>   message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.
>   See InnerException, if present, for more details.

The InnerException says: {"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:52154"}

My App.config is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="DocumentGeneratorSvcHttp">
                    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
                <binding name="DocumentGeneratorSvc" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="DocumentGeneratorSvcTcp" />
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>

        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://documentgenerator-dev/DocumentGenerator.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DocumentGeneratorSvcHttp"
                contract="DocGenServiceReference.IDocumentGeneratorSvc" name="DocumentGeneratorSvcDev" />
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:52154/DocumentGenerator.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DocumentGeneratorSvcHttp"
                contract="DocGenServiceReference.IDocumentGeneratorSvc" name="DocumentGeneratorSvcLocal" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Please help me find what the problem is.

Comment: Seems like two endpoint there.. did you try removing first endpoint ?

Comment: @AslamJiffry Yes. I removed the 1st endpoint and get the same error.

Comment: did u updated the service reference in client side. after changing the url? can you share the text in your .svc file. And your service layer code.

Comment: Also, can you try to use the visual studio built-in service reference wizard to try and "discover" this URL - let us know what was the result.